# Convert string to an array containing number and alphabet using regex in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

I have a string that contains either an alphabet or a number.

```
AB1D21E48EFGHI1K
```

I am trying to break that string into array as follows.

```
[0] => A
[1] => B
[2] => 1
[3] => D
[4] => 21
[5] => E
[6] => 48
[7] => E
[8] => F
[9] => G
[10] => H
[11] => I
[12] => 1
[13] => K
```

But, I am getting array as follow:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => AB
    [1] => 1
    [2] => D
    [3] => 21
    [4] => E
    [5] => 48
    [6] => EFGHI
    [7] => 1
    [8] => K
)
```

I have tried the following code so far.

```
$string = 'AB1D21E48EFGHI1K';
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: your desired output?

Comment: Use `([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]{1})` or simpler `(\d+|\w{1})`

Comment: @Mohammad, Thank you. It helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `+` after word character to matching with length `1`. So your regex should be

```
/([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z])/
```

You can make your regex simpler to

```
/\d+|\w/
```

The code changed to

```
$string = 'AB1D21E48EFGHI1K';
preg_match_all('/\d+|\w/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/YcNPF)

Comment: `[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: `\w` is NOT the same as `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @Toto You are right but in this case it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this way, it might be useful for you

```
<?php
$data = array(0 => AB,1 => 1, 2 => D, 3 => 21, 4 => E, 5 => 48, 6 => EFGHI, 7 => 1, 8 => K);

/*print "<pre>";
print_r($data);
print "<pre>";*/


$new_data = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value){

  if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $value)) // '/[^a-z\d]/i' should also work.
  {
    // string contains only english letters
    $arr1 = str_split($value);
    foreach($arr1 as $row => $val){
      $new_data[] = $val;
    }
  }else{
    $new_data[] = $value;
  }

}

/*
 print "<pre>";
 print_r($new_data);
 print "<pre>";*/

?>
```

Comment: Where `$data` comes from?

Comment: According to above question, I have created a $data array in which data store in user questions format according .